# Why my breaking point in bootstrap is not good grid not working

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, grid

I don't understand why my breaking point is at 800 px when i ask to be at 991 (lg and lower)in bootstrap 4  here is my code:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-6 fondNoir" id="menuTexte"> img</div>
        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 fondNoir" id="menuTexte"> Jeux</div>
        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 fondNoir" id="menuTexte"> Livres</div>
        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 fondNoir" id="menuTexte"> E-sport</div>
        <div class="col-xl-2 offset-xl-0 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 offset-sm-7 fondNoir" id="menuTexte"> Communauté</div>
        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 fondNoir" id="menuTexte"> Boutique</div>


    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of your breaking points are at 800px. If you see closely, they are working just as you specified them. You need to understand how grid system works in bootstrap.

#### Bootstrap Grid System

> *Grid breakpoints are based on minimum width media queries, meaning they apply to that one breakpoint and all those above it (e.g., .col-sm-4 applies to small, medium, large, and extra large devices, but not the first xs breakpoint).*

If nothing is specified for a certain screen size , it will be defaulted to 12 grid size ( you can consider it to be defaulted to `col-xs-12` if nothing is specifed)

---

## Working of your Program

1. #### XL Screens :

   When your snippet is run on a extra large screen or `xl`(>1200px), each of the divs take 2 grids worth of space (`col-xl-2` will apply to all).

2. #### LG Screens :

   When you transition from large screen or `lg`(992px - 1200px) , you have dropped below 1200px and now the `col-lg` will apply. So the grids will be divided as

   - **Divisions -**
   - 1st div - 6 grids ( `col-lg-6` ).
   - 2nd to 4th divs - 2 grids each in first row( `col-lg-6` ). Now all 12 grids of 1st row are used.
   - 5th and 6th divs - 2 grids( `col-lg-6` ) each in second row.

3. #### MD Screens :

   When you go below 992px, you enter medium screen range(768px - 992px), the divs will be placed as per `col-md` or if not specified for range below `lg`, they will default to `col-xs-12`. So the grids will be divided as

   - **Divisions -**
   - 1st div to 4th divs - 12 grids( defaulted to `col-xs-12` since nothing is specifed )
   - 5th div - 2 grids offset by 7 ( `col-md-2` and `offset-sm-7`)
   - 6th div - 12 grids ( defaulted to `col-xs-12` since nothing is specifed )

4. #### SM Screens :

   When you go below 768px, the divs will be given allocated grids just as  in case of **MD Screens** since nothing is specified for sm screens.

5. #### XS Screens :

   When you go below 576px, the divs will all remain same except for the 5th div in which case the `offset-sm-7` will no longer be applicable and all grids will align to the left occupying 12 grids each.

---

Hope you understand how your program is working and nothing is going abnormal or unexpected. If you still have any questions, ask in the comments.